# Reduce bitcoin blockchain size

Tags: bitcoind, block-size-increase

I have a freebsd server with a bitcoind server. But the blockchain is getting to large for me. So I just bought some new sas drives so I can keep it up. I now have 218GB of total space. 40GB is for the OS, programs and all files. The rest is for the blockchain(178GB). I do not want to buy more SAS drives than I have now.

I am afraid that the blockchain will get to big again in 1 or 2 years.
Is there a way to reduce the blockchain size or is there a cryptocurrency where this problem is solved?

Comment: Interesting, I run a full node too, and at the present time, it uses little over 90GB.

Comment: @FábioAntunes mine to but I didn't want to install bitcoind if I cant use it anymore in 1 year. But now pruning exists so I can continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this problem has been solved. Have a look at the pruning option. You can specify whatever maximum size you want to allow the blockchain to take up.